# Convergence/Divergence of summation

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence, summation, factorial

Is it possible to determine if the following sum converges as $k$ tends to infinity? Wolfram Alpha gave a version in terms of the incomplete gamma function however I didn't see how that could help me.
$$\sum_{n=0}^{k}\frac{k!\left(-1\right)^{n}}{x^{n}\left(k-n\right)!}$$

Answer (score 1):

Call your sum $f_k(x)$.  The exponential generating function of this is

$$ \eqalign{g(x,t) &= \sum_{k=0}^\infty f_k(x) t^k/k!\cr &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=n}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{x^n (k-n)!} t^k \cr
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n t^n e^t}{x^n} \cr
&= \frac{x e^t}{t+x} }$$
converging if $|t| < |x|$.  This has a pole at $t = -x$.  But if $f_k(x)$ converged
as $k \to \infty$, $g(x,t)$ would converge for all $t$, with no pole.  So it must diverge, in fact it must be unbounded.